# AutoIt DLL preloading possible?

Tags: dll, autoit

Is there a better way than opening and calling a .dll file every time?

```
Func getLife()    
    Local $hDLL = DllOpen("MyFirstDll.dll")
    Local $result = DllCall($hDLL, "int:cdecl", "getLife")
    If @error > 0 Then
        MsgBox(0, "Error", "Oh ups.. dll loading fail")
        Else
        MsgBox(0, "Result", $result[0])
    EndIf
    DllClose($hDLL)
EndFunc
```

In AutoHotkey it is possible to preload a .dll file. Is this also possible in AutoIt (to save performance)?

Comment: Sry for that Question. I mean the DLLClose() function close it after left scope. That is not true. Its only on termination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better way than opening and calling a .dll file every time?

Load and close the .dll file once (as opposed to every function call). Example (untested):

```
Global Const $g_sFileDll      = 'MyFirstDll.dll'
Global Const $g_sErrorDllLoad = 'Failed to load .dll file.' & @LF
Global Const $g_sErrorDllCall = 'Failed to call .dll file.' & @LF
Global Const $g_iCountDllCall = 10
Global Const $g_iDelayDllCall = 1000

Global       $g_hDLL          = DllOpen($g_sFileDll)

If $g_hDLL = -1 Then    
    ConsoleWrite($g_sErrorDllLoad)
    Exit    
EndIf

For $i1 = 1 To $g_iCountDllCall
    getLife($g_hDLL)
    Sleep($g_iDelayDllCall)    
Next

DllClose($g_hDLL)
Exit

Func getLife(ByRef $hDLL)
    Local $aResult = DllCall($hDLL, "int:cdecl", "getLife")

    If @error Then    
        ConsoleWrite($g_sErrorDllCall)    
    Else    
        ConsoleWrite('Result: ' & $aResult[0] & @LF)    
    EndIf

EndFunc
```